# using Aria vs InnoDB vs MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I was wondering (if anyone knows) if Aria database is crash safe . I had some tables with MyISAM which were getting corrupted very often and switch them to InnoDB . However innodb is a bit slower and uses more space. Does anyone know if Aria is good alternative to MyISAM and does not corrupt the table ?

Comment: and when i write Aria database i mean Aria storage engine :)

Comment: Even after 20 years of active development InnoDB is not 100% crash safe. Aria isn't widely used in production, so many bugs aren't discovered yet.

Comment: From the Aria FAQ: Aria 1.0 was basically a crash-safe non-transactional version of MyISAM. Aria 1.5 added more concurrency (multiple inserter) and some optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

We have millions of tables deployed running ARIA in production. It is  definitely a better choice over MyISAM as far as crashing and recovering from a crashed table. If you have high concurrent write neither are a option as they both only support table level locks. For tables with more write intensive operations stick with InnoDB, and with heavy write tables checkout TokuDB.

Answer (score 1):

Generic answer: Yes it is crash safe. But before switching to any db engine: there are some details you might want to consider.

A few quotes from the [documentation on Aria](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aria-faq/):

> In the current development phase Aria tables created with TRANSACTIONAL=1 are crash safe and atomic but not transactional because **changes in Aria tables can't be rolled back with the ROLLBACK command**. As we planned to make Aria tables fully transactional, we decided it was better to use the TRANSACTIONAL keyword from the start so so that applications don't need to be changed later.

quite sobering. Also

> Aria doesn't support indexes on virtual fields.

(that was a show stopper for me for some tables)

but less dramatic

> Storage of very small rows (< 25 bytes) are not efficient for PAGE
> format.

So consider your (future)requirements before changing an engine. And anyway MySQL does not and unlikely will ever support the Aria engine.